# How to find sizes and shapes of Microsoft Powerpoint objects?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, powerpoint

I have a slide with some hand-drawn circles on it. I'd like to get a list of the coordinates and radii (sizes) of them. Attached is an image and [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6iuzldlnom7cecy/circles.pptx?dl=0). Anyone have an idea how?
[image]

I started looking into computer vision techniques, but it seems like there should be a much more direct way.

Comment: Couldn't post the image. Link here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6iuzldlnom7cecy/circles.pptx?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with openCV the method HoughCircles() will do the job:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html

Are you familiar with Matlab? imfindcircles() will do it:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html

If this is a one time job you can post it as a job for someone else to do it for you for a small fee. Example: https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome

If you don't know any programming language and this is a one time job, you can do it manually. You can select each circle in photoshop, count the amount of pixels (and using the formulae of circumference = 2*pi*radius) find the radius. The center of mass of all the pixels will be the center of the circle.
It is a bit tricky to separate overlapping circles but you can do it by hand

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to get the coordinates/radii of the PowerPoint shapes or of the area the shapes subtend in an image exported from PPT or on the slide show screen during a PPT presentation.  In PPT, each shape has .Top .Left .Height and .Width properties, which give you the position and size.  Assuming .Height = .Width, then radius = .Width * .5  Ratios between the PPT coordinates and the final size of any image (in file or displayed on screen) should give you the size/position in pixels

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried openCV and had some success but it failed to find some circles while picking up false positives elsewhere. I will try Matlab today and see if it does better. Previously I just accessed the circle objects in powerpoint and got their width directly (diameter), but I would prefer to automate the process (i.e.: get width and ideally location for all selected shapes in PP).

Comment: Check your intermediate results (like results of edge detection) to find what is going wrong. Some preprocessing can reduce noise and improve results. .There are a few parameters in Hough circles that you can tune to improve the results.

Answer (score 0):

I found a suitable method using vector graphics.

1. Select all the circles in powerpoint, right click and 'save as a picture'. Use .emf (windows metafile) format (this option was only available on my windows machine, not mac).
2. Open the emf file in inkscape, and save it to an 'svg' format, which is ascii and human [readable](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands).
3. Extract the information from the path commands.

E.g.: Each circle is represented as a path object, with a line: 
d="m 36.527169,36.434607 c 0,-9.696733 9.075703,-17.551993 20.274845,-17.551993 11.194626,0 20.270329,7.85526 20.270329,17.551993 0,9.69264 -9.075703,17.552246 -20.270329,17.552246 -11.199142,0 -20.274845,-7.859606 -20.274845,-17.552246"

Here, the (x,y) following the 'm' character is the center of the circle, and the 12 (x,y) pairs following 'c' denote a 4-segment polybezier curve in which pairs 3,6,9,12 are the four compass points. Therefore in the above object, this is not a circle but an ellipse with axes ~ 20.27 and 17.55.